# java keylistener not called

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings

I have written a sample code using `KeyListener` in Java,
I have created a `JPanel`, then set its focusable to true, I have created a KeyListener, requested a focus and then added the KeyListener to my panel. But the methods for the keyListener are never called. It seems although I have requested focus, it does not focus.

Can anyone help?

```
listener = new KeyLis();
this.setFocusable(true);
this.requestFocus();
this.addKeyListener(listener);

 class KeyLis implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        currentver += 5;
         switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT : if(horizontalyInBounds()) currentPos-= 5;  
                 break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: if(horizontalyInBounds()) currentPos+= 5;  
                 break;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

If any runnable code should be needed:

```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.util.Random;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;


 public class test extends JFrame {

private AreaOfGame areaOfGame;

public test()
{
    super("");
    setVisible(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(200, 10, 400, 700);

    areaOfGame = new AreaOfGame();
    this.add(areaOfGame);

    startGame();
}

public int generateNext()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int n = r.nextInt(7);
    return n;
}

public void startGame()
{
    while(!areaOfGame.GameOver())
    {
        areaOfGame.startGame(generateNext());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame();
}


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AreaOfGame extends JPanel {


    private static final int rightside = 370;

    private int bottom;
    private int top;

    private int currentPos;
    private int currentver;
    private KeyLis listener;

    public AreaOfGame()
    {
        super();

        bottom = 650;
        top = 50;
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(20, 50, 350, 600);
        setVisible(true);


        this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        listener = new KeyLis();
        this.setFocusable(true);
        if(this.requestFocus(true))
            System.out.println("true");;
        this.addKeyListener(listener);


        currentPos = 150;
        currentver=0;
    }

    public void startGame(int n)
    {
        while(verticallyInBound()){
            System.out.println("anything");

        }


    }

    public boolean verticallyInBound()
    {
        if(currentPos<= bottom -50)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    public boolean GameOver()
    {
        if(top>= bottom){
            System.out.println("game over");
            return true;
        }

        else return false;
    }


    public boolean horizontalyInBounds()
    {
        if(currentPos<=rightside && currentPos>= 20)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }


class KeyLis implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("called");
            currentver += 5;
             switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT : if(horizontalyInBounds()) currentPos-= 5;  break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: if(horizontalyInBounds()) currentPos+= 5;  break;
            }
            repaint();


        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("called 3");
        }
}

}
```

Comment: It would help if you could give us your "KeyLis" class, maybe the problem's there.

Comment: thank you, i added the listener class

Comment: Hmmm... I think I had a similar problem at one time. Try calling the method "e.consume()" to the end of your keyPressed(KeyEvent e) method. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Just copy your code to the keyPressed method

Comment: I meant "at" instead of "to". Maybe that was confusing.

Comment: @BBB try adding a `System.out.println("something unique")` to each method of your listener. This will make sure that they aren't actually being called.

Comment: @eboix I added it but it didnt work :( . The methods are not called at all.

Comment: @Roflcoptr from copying the code do you mean asking for focus and stuff? cause the code for listening part is already in the keyPressed method.

Comment: @Jon I tried that too, but they seriously are not called at all

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your `while (true)` loops are locking your event thread.

Comment: Please see **edit 3** to my answer below for more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll bet that you're requesting focus before the JPanel has been rendered (before the top level window has either had `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` called), and if so, this won't work. Focus request will only be possibly granted *after* components have been rendered. Have you checked what your call to `requestFocus()` has returned? It must return true for your call to have any chance for a success. Also it's better to use `requestFocusInWindow()` rather than `requestFocus()`.

But more importantly, you shouldn't be using KeyListeners for this but rather key bindings, a higher level concept that Swing itself uses to respond to key presses.

**Edit**
An example of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestKeyListener extends JPanel {
   private KeyLis listener;

   public TestKeyListener() {
      add(new JButton("Foo")); // something to draw off focus
      listener = new KeyLis();
      this.setFocusable(true);
      this.requestFocus();
      this.addKeyListener(listener);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(300, 200);
   }

   private class KeyLis extends KeyAdapter {
      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
         case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            System.out.println("VK_LEFT pressed");
            break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            System.out.println("VK_RIGHT pressed");
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestKeyListener mainPanel = new TestKeyListener();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestKeyListener");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**Edit 2**
And the equivalent [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) using Key Bindings:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestKeyBindings extends JPanel {

   public TestKeyBindings() {
      add(new JButton("Foo")); // something to draw off focus
      setKeyBindings();
   }

   private void setKeyBindings() {
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition );

      String vkLeft = "VK_LEFT";
      String vkRight = "VK_RIGHT";
      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), vkLeft);
      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), vkRight);

      actionMap.put(vkLeft, new KeyAction(vkLeft));
      actionMap.put(vkRight, new KeyAction(vkRight));

   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(300, 200);
   }

   private class KeyAction extends AbstractAction {
      public KeyAction(String actionCommand) {
         putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, actionCommand);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvt) {
         System.out.println(actionEvt.getActionCommand() + " pressed");
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestKeyBindings mainPanel = new TestKeyBindings();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestKeyListener");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**Edit 3**
Regarding your recent SSCCE, your `while (true)` loops are blocking your Swing event thread and may prevent user interaction or painting from happening. Better to use a Swing Timer rather than `while (true)`. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BbbTest extends JFrame {

   private AreaOfGame areaOfGame;

   public BbbTest() {
      super("");
//      setVisible(true);
      this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.pack();
      setLayout(null);
      setBounds(200, 10, 400, 700);

      areaOfGame = new AreaOfGame();
      this.add(areaOfGame);
      setVisible(true);

      startGame();
   }

   public int generateNext() {
      Random r = new Random();
      int n = r.nextInt(7);
      return n;
   }

   public void startGame() {
      // while (!areaOfGame.GameOver()) {
      // areaOfGame.startGame(generateNext());
      // }

      areaOfGame.startGame(generateNext());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new BbbTest();
   }

   class AreaOfGame extends JPanel {

      private static final int rightside = 370;

      private int bottom;
      private int top;

      private int currentPos;
      private int currentver;
      private KeyLis listener;

      public AreaOfGame() {
         super();

         bottom = 650;
         top = 50;
         setLayout(null);
         setBounds(20, 50, 350, 600);
         setVisible(true);

         this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

         listener = new KeyLis();
         this.setFocusable(true);
         if (this.requestFocus(true))
            System.out.println("true");
         ;
         this.addKeyListener(listener);

         currentPos = 150;
         currentver = 0;
      }

      public void startGame(int n) {
         // while (verticallyInBound()) {
         // System.out.println("anything");
         // }

         int timeDelay = 50; // msecs delay
         new Timer(timeDelay , new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               System.out.println("anything");
            }
         }).start();

      }

      public boolean verticallyInBound() {
         if (currentPos <= bottom - 50)
            return true;
         return false;
      }

      public boolean GameOver() {
         if (top >= bottom) {
            System.out.println("game over");
            return true;
         }

         else
            return false;
      }

      public boolean horizontalyInBounds() {
         if (currentPos <= rightside && currentPos >= 20)
            return true;
         else
            return false;
      }

      class KeyLis implements KeyListener {

         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("called");
            currentver += 5;
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
               if (horizontalyInBounds())
                  currentPos -= 5;
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               if (horizontalyInBounds())
                  currentPos += 5;
               break;
            }
            repaint();

         }

         @Override
         public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("called 3");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually these are all done after my frame has had pack() and setVisible(true).If using key bindings is the only choice I will do that, but I would really like to know why this does not work, because no body seemed to have this problem before, I checked for null pointers, for focuses, for methods being called, the listener being added, but non worked.

Comment: @BBB: again, have you checked with your `requestFocus()` method call has returned? Is it returning true or false?

Comment: it is returning false all the time

Comment: this is actually what I have mentioned in my question, although I request, it seems it is not focused , meaning that it returns false and I dont know how to make it return true.

Comment: @BBB: my point exactly. Then you have no hope for success unless you change something. Better if you could create and post a small compilable and runnable program that we can run and that demonstrates your problem so we can see it for ourselves, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @BBB: now an SSCCE that uses key bindings for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thankssss :D it is now called, i just added that JButton you added :D and now they get called, I dont have any idea why this might cause the listener to be called but thanks :D

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, I also added the timer, and now it works really fine :D Thanks for the time and help

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the "TAB" button to switch between the buttons and the key listener.
I have a program with one button that after I press it, the key listener does not work.
I realized that if you press the "TAB" button, the "Attention" or "focus" of the program returns to the key listener.

maybe this will help: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ch03_08.htm