# Keylistener not working for JPanel

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to do something when one of the arrow keys are pressed using the KeyListener in my JPanel class. Here is my code:

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    public TestPanel(){
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("Right");

        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left");
        }

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

My main method adds a new instance of this panel to a frame and displays it. Do I need to add the keylistener to the JFrame? In my case, this would be difficult and inefficient, so I would like to make it work with this JPanel if possible. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Key Bindings code that does not work either:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

//Constructor
public GamePanel(){

    setupKeyBinding();
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();


}

private void setupKeyBinding() {
    int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    InputMap inMap = getInputMap(condition);
    ActionMap actMap = getActionMap();

    inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "Left");
    actMap.put("Left", new leftAction());
}

private class leftAction extends AbstractAction {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("test");
       }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //some other game info
}
}
```

Can someone tell me why this doesnt work either? (my second action listener is for other stuff needed for my game)

Comment: Another idea could be making an inner class and use something like:    "this.addKeyListener( inner class/anonymous inner class );"

Comment: possible duplicate of [java keylistener not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482268/java-keylistener-not-called)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you search this problem, you'll see that it is asked and has been solved many times.

- KeyListeners need to be on the focused component to work. One solution is to give your component the focus after first making it focusable.
- Better by a long shot however is to use Key Bindings. Google the tutorial on this.

Please have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482268/java-keylistener-not-called) for more on this, including many of the gory details.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into key bindings, but for this matter I have looked at various solutions and cannot see what I am doing differently. How do I give my component the focus?I thought I did so by using requestFocusInWindow()

Comment: Focus behavior varies by platform; moreover, a `KeyListener` will be fragile in this regard if there are _any_ other focusable components.

Comment: @user2373733 Key bindings is the way to go. Just drop your KeyListener: it will save you some time and avoid future bugs.

Comment: So I read the oracle documentation and went over your example and tried using key bindings, but it didnt work, so I went and copied your code for the keybinding and tried it, and it still doesnt work. No clue what to do at this point

Comment: @user2373733: what you must do is create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). If we are to help you with this bug, you or us must isolate and identify the bug, something hard for us to do without an sscce.

Comment: Ah whoops, that means what I did above is actually correct in that context?

Comment: Well anyways since my initial question was answered, I will just post another question later

Answer (score 8):

For reference, I've create an example using your approach; while it works, it also suggests a focus problem elsewhere in your code. [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) avoid this, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).

Addendum: Here's my working key binding.

```
private static class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final String LEFT = "Left";
    private Action left = new AbstractAction(LEFT) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(LEFT);
        }
    };
    private static final String RIGHT = "Right";
    private Action right = new AbstractAction(RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(RIGHT);
        }
    };

    public TestPanel() {
        this.getInputMap().put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), LEFT);
        this.getActionMap().put(LEFT, left);
        this.getInputMap().put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), RIGHT);
        this.getActionMap().put(RIGHT, right);
    }
}
```

Original SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531380/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new TestPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TestPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

        public TestPanel() {

            this.addKeyListener(this);
            this.setFocusable(true);
            this.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                System.out.println("Right");
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                System.out.println("Left");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I have no idea what could be taking the focus. I set all my other panels being added to my frame to unfocusable while testing to make sure nothing would interfere. I am trying out key bindings now, though I am having a bit of trouble being new to a lot of this stuff

Comment: I have added that code to my post, I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me why that doesnt work either!

Comment: I've added a working example above; let us know if you post a new question.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to do some more research before doing so. I have asked my teacher about my issue, and multiple other people, but no one can figure it out. Basically it only works if my panel has the focus. I thought this only applied to key listeners

Comment: Absent more context, it's hard to say; did you try each of the three input maps?

Answer (score 4):

For receives key events on `JPanel` you must set focus:

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocus();
```

the `JPanel` now has focus, so it receives key events

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things: I added comp.setFocusable(true); to the component comp that listens to key events, and I added comp.requestFocus(); to each action which caused comp to lose the focus.

Comment: This is a hack at the best of times and is easily broken the moment that the window loses focus or another component which steals focus - the correct answer is to use the key bindings API

Comment: @MadProgrammer - if the "correct" approach is to use key bindings, then why the heck does the KeyListener API even exist?

Comment: @JohnCalcote Look into the JavaDocs. `KeyListener` was added in 1.1, key bindings were added in 1.3 - key bindings were added to solve the issues that `KeyListener` created (amongst other things). The JavaDocs for `JComponent` even state it *"Comprehensive keystroke handling. See the document How to Use Key Bindings, an article in The Java Tutorial, for more information."*.  Does that mean you should never use `KeyListener`, no, it means that you first need to understand your requirements and choose the best API to solve the problem. Key bindings fix the "requires focus" issue

Comment: @JohnCalcote And, in relationship to this question, key bindings is the better API as it prevents the need to constantly hack around the focusability issues, as focus is not treated the same across multiple platforms

Comment: @JohnCalcote It's a bit like asking *"why do we have `java.time` when we already have `java.util.Date` and related APIs"* - development doesn't stand still.  The ideas which were originally implemented don't always hold up over time and sometimes "better" approaches come along.  In this, key bindings, provide generally better solution in most case, not all, so you can still use `KeyListener` for those times key bindings don't fulfil the requirements of the problem, just beware you understand the pros and cons of both APIs