# How do I draw on a JPanel from multiple outside classes?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, custom-painting

I am currently making a game with a main menu and a world where you actually play.

I have a class called `Game`, which inherits from JPanel and implements the `Runnable`, `MouseListener`, `KeyListener` and `ActionListener` interfaces
(only important parts included)

I also have two classes `InWorldHandler` and `OutWorldHandler` for handling the mechanics in the world and outside of it respectively.

The `Game` class:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener, ActionListener
{
    protected JFrame frame;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(25, this);

    private World world;
    private Player player = new Player();

    private boolean draw;

    Game(World world)
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Minecraft 2D");
        this.world = world;
        player.enterWorld(world, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        if(draw)
        {
            g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

            draw = false;
            //Here, the in-game mechanics should be handled
            if(player.inWorld())
            {
                Chunk chunk = player.getLoadedChunk();
                for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
                    {
                        Block block = chunk.getBlockAt(x, y);
                        BufferedImage texture = block.getTexture();

                        g2d.drawImage(block.getTexture(), x*32, y*32, texture.getWidth()*2, texture.getHeight()*2, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Here, the out-game mechanics should be handled
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        this.repaint();
        draw = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        draw = true;

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(518, 540));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Both the other classes have empty bodies currently. I just have no idea how to do that.

I want the `InWorldHandler` class to draw on the panel when the player is in game, and the `OutWorldHandler` class when the player is in the main menu, both called in the `Game` class. How do I do that?

Comment: Take it step by step. First get a `JFrame` to properly display one `JPanel`, say game panel.  The posted code does not. Then have it display *another* `JPanel` say menu panel. To switch between two panel learn how to use [CardLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870789/3992939)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a single `JPanel`, why don't you try with a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and switch whether to show the `InnerWorld` or the `OuterWorld` according to a flag that determines where in the program you're at.

As you're implementing `KeyListener`, I think that's for you to be able to move your character, please take a look at the accepted answer on this question: [Keylistener not working for JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530775/keylistener-not-working-for-jpanel) and use `KeyBindings` instead.

Also avoid the use of `setMimimum/Maximum/PreferredSize()` and override those methods instead: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Take this code as an example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private boolean status;
    private JPanel[] cards;
    private CardLayout cl;
    private JPanel gamePane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Game().createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        button = new JButton("Switch Worlds");
        status = true; //True = Inner / False = Outer

        cl = new CardLayout();

        gamePane = new JPanel(cl);
        cards = new JPanel[2];

        cards[0] = new InnerWorld();
        cards[1] = new OuterWorld();

        gamePane.add(cards[0], "innerWorld");
        gamePane.add(cards[1], "outerWorld");

        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            status = !status;
            if (status) {
                cl.show(gamePane, "innerWorld");
            } else {
                cl.show(gamePane, "outerWorld");
            }
        });

        frame.add(gamePane);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class InnerWorld extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawString("Inner World", 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class OuterWorld extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawString("Outer World", 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: It worked, but now I got the problem that when I press the JButton the key is not reciognized anymore (I used the main Panel for the key bindings)

Comment: @Keheck please ask another question in the site, showing what you've done so that we can provide better help, remember to post an [mcve] as in my answer

Comment: @Frakcool I solved it myself, but I will still ask the question and answer it, so others won't have to ask :)