# Why are the keybindings not working with CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

In my question [How do I draw on a JPanel from multiple outside classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042979/how-do-i-draw-on-a-jpanel-from-multiple-outside-classes) Frakcool gave me the advice to use key bindings, and one thing didn't work: When the JButton put another JPanel infront of the frame, the Keybinding didn't respond. This is the code:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel[] statePanels;
private CardLayout layout;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton button;
private String status;

void initAndShow()
{
    //Init stuff
    mainPanel = new JPanel(layout);
    statePanels = new JPanel[2];
    button = new JButton("Exit");
    status = "Menu";

    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        status = status.equals("Menu") ? "World" : "Menu";
        layout.show(mainPanel, status);
    });

    statePanels[0] = new OutWorldHandler();
    statePanels[1] = new InWorldHandler();

    mainPanel.add(statePanels[0], "Menu");
    mainPanel.add(statePanels[1], "World");

    mainPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('f'), "close");
    mainPanel.getActionMap().put("close", this);

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

The expected output was that when I allways pressed `f` the console would print out "hi", but it only did as long as I didn't press the button

Comment: The problem is, by default, getInputMap will return a “When has focus” mapping, thus means that mainPanel will need to have focus in order to trigger the bindings. Use the [getInputMap(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap(int)) variant and pass WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, then it will trigger when ever the window is focused

Comment: @MadProgrammer And I thought I had the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key bindings aren't particularly complex, but they can take a little bit of getting use to.  To this end, it's useful to have [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) on hand, for reference.

One of the goals of the key bindings API is configurability, allowing us more control over determining when a key stroke should trigger an event.

The [`JComponent#getInputMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap()) method returns a mapping which is bound to the "when has focused" context.  This means that the component will need to have focus (and be focusable obviously) before a binding will be triggered.

If you want the binding to be triggered at a different level, then you need to use [`JComponent#getInputMap(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap(int)) and pass it one of the three available contexts:

- [`JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
- [`JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_FOCUSED)
- [`JComponent. WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)

Which you use will depend on your needs, but I'm generally lazy and go for `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` when I want a "global" state

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me: I simply added a statement to the `button.addActionListener` lambda that put the focus on `mainPanel`: `mainPanel.grabFocus();`.

The full code then looked something like this:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {
    status = status.equals("Menu") ? "World" : "Menu";

    layout.show(mainPanel, status);
    button.setText("Exit " + status);
    mainPanel.grabFocus();
});
```

Comment: Don't use grabFocus(). Read the API for the grabFocus()N method. It will tell your the better method to use.