# Java get keyboard key typed in a function

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

So I am making a game in java, and I am currently working with keyboard input. I have a keylistener class setup called `KeyboardManager` and in it a static function that detects if a key is being held down. here is the code for that class:

```
public class KeyboardManager implements KeyListener {

    public static Map<Integer, Boolean> keys;

    public KeyboardManager () {
        keys = new HashMap<>();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys.put(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keys.put(e.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

    public static boolean isKeyDown(int key) {
        if (!keys.containsKey(key)) return false;
        return keys.get(key);
    }
}
```

The `isKeyDown` function works perfectly fine, and I use it for player movement, but if I use it for opening a gui, like a player inventory, as you would imagine, it opens and closes every tick. I am looking for a way to do what I have now, but with `keyTyped` instead of `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`. The challenge here, obviously is that there is no way to tell when the keytype ends. For example, in Unity, when you are coding in c# you can do something like `Input.GetKeyDown("E")` and it would test for a keytype, whereas `Input.GetKey("E")` would detect if it is being held down. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`keyTyped` is fired upon key release, so instead of checking elsewhere for whether or not a key is pressed, you could add your event response into the event handling function itself:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_I) {
        if (!isInventoryOpen) {
            openInventory();
        } else {
            closeInventory();
        }
    } else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_M) {
        // ...
    } // else if ...
}
```

If you have a complex set of interactions, you could create an abstract class with a unique subclass for each action, containing the applicable key code and the action to perform. Then, you could store a list or map of all actions to be used in your `keyTyped` and use the event's keycode to find the action with that keycode.

Comment: This is a fine way to do it, but I have a static class and want a static function to test if the key was typed. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @oriont Depending on the desired behavior (e.g. how long your static `isKeyTyped` method would return true after a key is typed), you could store another `Map<Integer, Boolean>` of typed keys and flip a keycode to `true` in `keyTyped` and then upon accessing it in `isKeyTyped`, flip the keycode back to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In the project I'm working on, my key Listeners are tied to certain panels being visible. (same key has variations of a similar action, such as `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` for submissions)

You might be able to implement a middle man flag, something to toggle when the key is pressed and toggled back when the key can be pressed/registered again.

This link, [java keylistener not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482268/java-keylistener-not-called) ,was super useful for me as I required keyBindings as well (TextField and JPanel listeners)

Comment: @Vulcan 's comment on his post is along the same lines as to Where I was going with a middle-man flag